# How to generate .classpath using mvn eclipse:eclipse for multiple pom.xml files?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a java project with a parent pom.xml and which will have, say, 3 child modules with a pom.xml in each. In case of a single pom, i usually use mvn eclipse:eclipse to get the .classpath file, which i can use in eclipse to resolve the classpath. Please tel me a simple way to obtain such a .classpath file in case of multiple poms. Note:I any way tried to run mvn eclipse:eclipse in individual modules and later manually consolidated to one .classpath file, which worked too. Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Let me check.

Comment: The child modules, that are supposed to be part of the parent project, appears to be separate sub project when I choose "import" -> "existing maven projects". But ignoring the project construct, it anyway works.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt Eclipse create such files,if you choose "import" -> "maven project"? Mine does ;) To import subprojects, too, you need to click the main/pom project and choose "import" -> "existing maven projects". These will also appear in Eclipse.